# Why does a suspend function call in a lambda, within a CoroutineScope, produce an error?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have a retry policy which takes in a lambda, launches a `CoroutineScope`, increments a retry counter, checks if the maximum retries are reached, calculates a `waitTime` based on the retry count, delays the scope for this time and finally calls the lambda:

```
        fun connectionRetryPolicy(block: () -> Unit) {

            Timber.d("connectionRetryPolicy: called")

            // Launch the coroutine to wait for a specific delay
            val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main)
            scope.launch {

                // Get and increment the current retry counter
                val counter = retryCounter.getAndIncrement()

                // Check if the counter is smaller than the maximum retry count and if so, wait a bit and execute the given function
                if (counter < maxRetry) {

                    // Calculate the time to be waited
                    val waitTime: Long = (2f.pow(counter) * baseDelayMillis).toLong()

                    // Delay the scope for the calculated time
                    delay(waitTime)

                    // Execute the given function
                    block()

                }

                // Else, throw an exception
                else {

                    throw FirebaseNetworkException("Retry count reached")

                }

            }

        }
```

This method is called to recursively call a suspend function as the lambda, like this:

```
    private suspend fun connectToGooglePlayBillingService(): BillingResult? {

        Timber.d("connectToGooglePlayBillingService: called")

        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->

            // If the billingClient is not already ready, start the connection
            if (!playStoreBillingClient.isReady) {

                // Start the connection and wait for its result in the listener
                playStoreBillingClient.startConnection(object: BillingClientStateListener {

                    override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

                        Timber.d("onBillingServiceDisconnected: called")

                        // Retry to connect using the RetryPolicies
                        RetryPolicies.connectionRetryPolicy { connectToGooglePlayBillingService() }

                    }

                    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult?) {

                        // There is code that does not matter here

                    }

                })

            }

        }

    }
```

Now, Lint tells me, that `connectToGooglePlayBillingService` cannot be called inside the lambda because it's a suspend function and it needs to be called inside a `CoroutineScope`. And as you can see, I do call the lambda inside a `CoroutineScope` in `connectionRetryPolicy`.

Is this a bug in Lint or do I do something wrong here? I know, I can create a new `CoroutineScope` inside the lambda and then call `connectToGooglePlayBillingService` and I am not sure if this is so wise, regarding performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
fun connectionRetryPolicy(block: () -> Unit)
```

with

```
fun connectionRetryPolicy(block: suspend () -> Unit)
```

Because your `block()` will run inside a coroutine, but the other method doesn't know that.

Comment: Oh my god, now I feel dumb. I actually tried this already, but added `fun` after the `suspend`. Well, thank you so much for your fast answer!